# I am using wordpress and want to adjust responsive width of the header. the menu collapses when 1200px i want it to be collapsed at 800 px

Tags: themes, responsive

I am using academia wordpress theme and want to adjust responsive width of the header. the menu collapses when 1200px I want it to be collapsed at 800px. *sorry for bad English*.

The menu is collapsing at `1200px` I wish if it collapse at `800px`, please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: If you didn't write code at all then check online tutorial... SO is not a homework bot and we don't get paid either to post these comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
   //collapse
}
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
   //don't collapse
}
```

Comment: where to paste this media querry

Comment: Do you need any of the file?

Comment: You have to put it in the css file loaded by the HTML file: